# How load video and audio content in tt_news record

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tt-news

I would like to to add media content as videos and audios to my website. We are using TYPO3 7.6 and `tt_news` 7.6.1. I tried to use `rgmediaimages` extension but this does not work in our version of TYPO3. Someone know how to put media content in a `tt_news` record in another way?

Comment: If the website is new, try to switch to ext:news. Just in case you might not have known that news is the current standard news extension (by the same author as rgmediaimages)

Comment: We can not switch to ext:news because the website is live and has many content in tt_news

Comment: I should have known, sorry for the useless comment. I guess you also know there's a migration tool, but it means some work

Comment: you could just abuse some text field to insert youtube/soundcloud urls and then template those accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depend on your knowledge of extension development, but you can easily extend tt_news with new fields and functionally. There are some hooks you can use:
[documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/tt_news/ExtNews/ExtendingTtNews/Index.html).

And better option is, as said in previous comments to switch to news extension. For that you can create local backup of website, do the migration and upload changes.

Comment: The solution was extend tt_news how you said and I have the another idea to do in a development environment.